# npm permission issue in laravel docker setup

Tags: laravel, docker, npm

If I try and run the following in my docker setup

```
    docker-compose run --rm npm run dev
```

I get the following error

```
> dev
> npm run development

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
 }

> development
 > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide- 
 modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /var/www/html
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -- 
progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

Seems like a permissions issue but where how do I give permission for this, for root, uncertain where it is

This is the docker-compose.yml where I'm adding npm in docker
so not sure where to give permission to /root/.npm/_logs as that seems to be in  the application outside docker?

```
  version: '3'

  networks:
  laravel:

services:
 nginx:
image: nginx:stable-alpine
container_name: nginx
ports:
  - "8080:80"
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
  - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
depends_on:
  - php
  - mysql
networks:
  - laravel

mysql:
image: mysql:5.7.22
container_name: mysql
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
env_file:
  - src/.env
networks:
  - laravel

php:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
container_name: php
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
ports:
  - "9000:9000"
networks:
  - laravel
npm:
 image: node:latest
container_name: npm
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
working_dir: /var/www/html
entrypoint: [ 'npm', '--no-bin-links' ]
networks:
  - laravel
```

Comment: I think you need to give permission to this folder `/root/.npm/_logs`.

Comment: Where and how ?

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /root/.npm/_logs`

Comment: There's nothing with that name in local machine, or docker containers with that folder name

Comment: Try updating your node docker image: `docker pull node:latest`

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue while compiling assets form inside a docker container running a laravel app.

**Background:**
I created the app to run as a docker container(following instructions on laravel docs), which uses laravel sail to build the containers.
After creating and running the containers, i logged into the app container(i.e.;laravel.test).

- Inside, I ran `npm install` to install node dependencies.
- Ran `npm run dev`
  While webpack was able to successfully compile the assets, it also produced an error:

```
    glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
      errno: -13,
      code: 'EACCES',
      syscall: 'scandir',
      path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
    }
```

Since the assets were successfully compiled, i assumed it's a notice-ish error, nothing major. Still i wanted to see if i could get rid of it.

**How i got rid of it:**
When I entered the container, I was logged in as `root`. I looked up to see what other users are available in the system. I run `cat /etc/passwd` and noticed this line:

`sail:x:1000:1000::/home/sail:/bin/bash`

Which means `sail` was a user on the system.
So on the shell, i ran `su sail` to change into `sail` user.
Then ran `npm run dev` and the process finished successfully without producing that error.

```
    root@f0fec81c3439:/var/www/html# su sail
    sail@f0fec81c3439:/var/www/html$ npm run dev
```

Answer (score 8):

In your dockerfile, add a line with:

```
npm config set cache /tmp --global
```

Or any cache folder of choice.

Comment: We added `mkdir /tmp/npm &&  chmod 2777 /tmp/npm && chown 1000:1000 /tmp/npm && npm config set cache /tmp/npm --global` and solved a similar problem with another npm project.

Comment: @sneaky I'd recommend a small change to your suggestion. I'd flip the order of the last two commands and have it end with `npm config set cache /tmp/npm --global && chown -R 1000:1000 /tmp/npm` so that any file created when `npm config` is called ends up owned by the right user.

Comment: That sounds more correct than my solution.

Answer (score 6):

I tried it with `npm run --cache /var/cache/ COMMAND` and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, npm has been ugraded, I have to downgrade npm version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).